# Am getting error in scala programming while integrating spark streaming with kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Am trying to add some imports , but when I add 
`import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.kafkautils` its showing the below error

object kafka is not a member of the object org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.kafkautils

working on eclipse with
 scala ide 4.7
version 2.11.11,
spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 jar files,
kafka 2.11 jars,
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0 jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using s`park-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0 jar` then the KafkaUtils is available in `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010` this package.
So import

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
```

and not

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.kafkautils
```

Hope this hepls!

Comment: Thank you Shankar, that solved my problem , but am getting error  at val kafkastream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,"localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group",Map("mytopic"->5))

Comment: near KafkaUtils.createDirectStream its showing error

Comment: Here is simple example try this one https://github.com/spirom/spark-streaming-with-kafka/blob/master/src/main/scala/SimpleStreaming.scala

Comment: I tried as per the example. it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did not work in Pyspark. Even i used from pyspark.streaming.kafka010 import KafkaUtils